# Connect RFID/NFC reader/writer using UART or SPI?

Tags: serial, uart, rfid

I have an Raspberry Pi model B, and I want to hook up this RFID/NFC reader I got. [This is the one](http://www.elechouse.com/elechouse/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=90_93&products_id=2156) I have.

It has TX, RX, VCC, and GND. When I try to hook up TXD -> RXD and RXD -> TXD (or TXD -> TXD **doesn't matter**), I cannot get it to respond to anything I do. I have tried 5v and 3.3v, but I prefer UART as it seems more documented, so I go with 5v.

To test if the ports even work, I hooked up RXD to TXD on the Raspberry Pi to create a loopback. Using `minicom -b 9600 -o -D /dev/ttyAMA0` to read from the port, I could see my keystrokes. Perfect. But, when I connect my device and I do the same command, I see nothing when I try to read the cards I have, even though the LED blinks when it reads a card.

[image]

This should work, but it does not. I did try hooking up the RFID device to my Arduino, then load a library, and I could read the cards through the serial monitor easily. And yes, I did try switching around TXD and RXD. I also tried using `screen 9600 /dev/ttyAMA0` but unfortunately that didn't work either.

Anyone out there who can help? Thanks!

Comment: I hope the output from the reader is 3.3V.  Any higher and you will eventually kill the gpio.  Also, connect the Pi ground to the RFID ground.

Comment: Does the reader output any voltage? It shouldn't. The reader should receive voltage to power it on. Also, it works with 3.3v and 5v, so it shouldn't be a problem (5v for UART / 3.3v for SPI).

Comment: The TXD to RXD connection is a wire.  Just like any other wire.  If you put a meter on the wire you can measure that voltage relative to the ground wire.  I'd try that.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have a voltmeter, so I can't measure that. But I'm sure it's fine.

Comment: It's your Pi.  It will be fine as long as the voltage is no less than 0V and no greater than 3.3V.  Anything outside those limits will eventually damage a Pi gpio.

Comment: Everyone else does it this way, so I'm sure it will be fine.

Comment: I think the key to your success here is @joan's "Also" statement: Please make sure that the RFID reader and the Pi share a common GND. Otherwise the voltage levels don't align between the two devices and you get nothing (or garbage) read via the UART.

Comment: Did that already. I just didn't want to add possible confusion to the sketch I made.